# glassfish, tomcat and jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, jersey

If I use Glassfish and only need jersey for jax-rs and grizzly for servlet/jsp, will glassfish load all other Java EE components I don't need and take more up more resources than just running jersey/tomcat or will glassfish just load jersey/grizzly and will use almost the same resources? I have tried running starting default glassfish and default tomcat, glassfish takes much more ram.

Is there any reason not to run jersey with tomcat? maybe because the integration is done better by Glassfish?

Comment: Have you looked at [TomEE+](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)? It might have everything you are looking for without plugging anything extra into it.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems like jersey is the most well implemented jax-rs out there, apache cxf doesn't seem to have good reviews.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of people who use Jersey with Tomcat. Tomcat is a servlet container only but will not interfere with other Java EE technologies that you choose to support through other means (e.g. Jersey). You may have to manage some of the initialization of the frameworks, etc. that other full-J2EE containers like Glassfish already provide, but it shouldn't be too painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'web profile' to help minimize the download, initial memory and start-up time.

The most recent web profile is http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/3.1.2.2/release/glassfish-3.1.2.2-web.zip

The start-up time is between Tomcat and the GlassFish 'full' profile.

The web profile includes an integrated implementation of Jersey.